# How to set up html email from rules?

Tags: theming, emails

I want to send a HTML email from rules but I cannot get it correct.

Installed mime, html, mail. Created rule. only a trigger and action send html email.
In the rule: no message key defined, subject is something like [node:nid], body is [node:body]

Made a template at campain monitor, now i have foo.html. Renamed foo.html to mimemail-message.tpl.php in default theme directory and put [node:id] and [node:body] on the correct place. Soo, the css is in the tpl file.

1) When testing I get an html email (logo is visible) but no colors. 
Installed and configured: sites/all/libraries/emogrifier/emogrifier.php
Mailsystem is using mime, mime is using full html filter including emogrifier.
No change in the result. 
I read the message with gmail. Adblockes disabled.

Any suggestion what to do ?

2) How to get replacement of the tokens. Which tokens are available for this tpl file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I forgot to enable the module  mimemail_compress. After enabling this it was solved.

Comment: Done thxs. Gewoon vanuit NL 

Comment: Welcome back ...